# Bash script : Print all lines between two pattern in variables with slashes

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sed, awk

I have a directory that looks like so :

```
/path/to/files/data-file.1
/path/to/files/data-file.2
/path/to/files/data-file.3
/path/to/files/data-file.4
/path/to/files/data-file.5
/path/to/files/data-file.6
```

I'd like to make a script to list all the files between two values in variables like the following :

```
#!/bin/bash
fileA="/path/to/files/data-file.2"
fileB="/path/to/files/data-file.5"
ls -v /path/to/files/*-file.[0-9]* | sed -n '/$fileA/,/$fileB/p'
```

with the output :

```
/path/to/files/data-file.2
/path/to/files/data-file.3
/path/to/files/data-file.4
/path/to/files/data-file.5
```

However, the sed command does not seem to work. I'm guessing because of the slashes in the variables. Is there a way to overcome this without changing the variables ? I'd like to use this bit of code in a script where fileA and fileB are dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a different delimiter if you escape it at its first occurrence, so the slashes will not confuse `sed`. However, note that using single quotes will result in `bash` not substituting variables, so in your example, `sed` looks for `$fileA` and `$fileB` literally, as the variables does not get expanded. You need to use double quotes if you use variables.

So, something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
fileA="/path/to/files/data-file.2"
fileB="/path/to/files/data-file.5"
ls -v /path/to/files/*-file.[0-9]* | sed -n "\@$fileA@,\@$fileB@p'
```

Comment: I've tried so many different syntaxes but I missed the part where you need to escape the first occurence of the delimiter ! Thank you it works like a charm !